# What is the solution of $\sin z=\cosh 4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, transcendental-equations

What is the solution of $\sin z=\cosh 4$?

By putting $z=x+iy$ I managed to find that the real part of $z$ is $x= \frac \pi 2+2n\pi $, but the imaginary part is contradictory giving negative value of $\cosh x$.

The answer is given to be $\frac \pi 2+2n\pi \pm \cosh 4$.

Comment: Do you know the exponential forms of $\sin$ and $\cosh$?

Comment: yes but i want to solve it other way

Comment: That's going to be tricky since $\sin^{-1} \cosh 4 = \frac{\pi}{2} - 4 \mathrm{i}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation can be written
$$
e^{iz}-e^{-iz}=2i\cosh 4
$$
or
$$
e^{2iz}-2ie^{iz}\cosh 4-1=0
$$
Set $w=e^{iz}$, and solve the quadratic $w^2-2iw\cosh 4-1=0$:
$$
w=i\cosh4\pm\sqrt{-\cosh^24+1}=i(\cosh4\pm \sinh4)
$$
Thus the roots are
$$
ie^4,\quad ie^{-4}
$$
Now, if $z=x+iy$, the first root gives
$$
e^{-y}e^{ix}=ie^{4}=
e^4\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{2}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
$$
so
$$
z=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi-4i
$$
Similarly, the second root gives the solutions
$$
z=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi+4i
$$

---

If you want to go the $\sin(x+iy)$ way, consider
$$
\sin x\cos(iy)+\cos x\sin(iy)=\cosh4
$$
that can be rewritten using $\cos(iy)=\cosh y$ and $\sin(iy)=i\sinh y$:
$$
\sin x\cosh y+i\cos x\sinh y=\cosh 4
$$
Thus you have
$$
\sin x\cosh y=\cosh 4, \qquad \cos x\sinh y=0
$$
From the second equation you get $\cos x=0$ or $y=0$; the case $y=0$ is incompatible with the first equation, because $\cosh4>1$. So we have
$$
x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
x=-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi
$$
but the second set of solution must be excluded, because it would give the incompatible relation $-\cosh y=\cosh4$. So you remain with the first set of solutions, from which
$$
\cosh y=\cosh4
$$
and so $y=\pm4$.

Comment: Fantastic answer thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\cosh 4$ is just a number, so we apply inverse functions...  \begin{align*}
    \sin z &= \cosh 4 \\
    z = \sin^{-1} \cosh 4 + 2\pi k &\text{ or } z = \pi - \sin^{-1} \cosh 4 + 2 \pi k, \text{ for any integer $k$}.
\end{align*}  Suppose we already know $\sin^{-1}\cosh 4 = \frac{\pi}{2} - 4\mathrm{i}$.  Then $$
    z = \frac{\pi}{2} - 4\mathrm{i} + 2\pi k \text{ or } z = \frac{\pi}{2} + 4\mathrm{i} + 2\pi k, \text{ for any integer $k$}.
$$
We could perhaps simplify this to $z = \frac{\pi}{2} \pm 4\mathrm{i} + 2\pi k, \text{ for any integer $k$}$.  This is as close as I can get any answer to the form you gave (since $\cosh 4 = 27.308\dots \neq 4\mathrm{i}$).